# Using a non-constant value inside "while", gives me this error, what can I do?

Tags: math, verilog, synthesis, quartus

I'm trying to make addition and subtraction of floating point. My guide is a book "Computer Arithmetic and Verilog HDL Fundamentals" by Cavanagh. Inside the module he use a code for aligning exponents as I show as follows.

```
  always @ (oper_1 or oper_2)
  begin 


  exp_a = oper_1 [31:24];
  exp_b = oper_2 [31:24];


  fract_a = oper_1 [23:0];
  fract_b = oper_2 [23:0];


  // bias exponents 


  exp_a_bias = exp_a + 8'b0111_1111;
  exp_b_bias = exp_b + 8'b0111_1111;


 // align fractions 


 if (exp_a_bias < exp_b_bias)
 ctrl_align = exp_b_bias - exp_a_bias;

 while (ctrl_align)
 begin
 fract_a = fract_a >> 1;
 exp_a_bias = exp_a_bias + 1;
 ctrl_align = ctrl_align - 1;
 end


  if (exp_b_bias < exp_a_bias)
  ctrl_align = exp_a_bias - exp_b_bias;

  while (ctrl_align)  // heres comes the troubles
  begin
  fract_b = fract_b >> 1;
  exp_b_bias = exp_b_bias + 1;
  ctrl_align = ctrl_align - 1;
  end
```

Quartus II give me the following error:

Error (10119): Verilog HDL Loop Statement error at ADD_SUB_FLO.v(40): loop with non-constant loop condition must terminate within 250 iterations

I searched and it seems that since Quartus can't be sure what will be the size of "ctrl_align" resultant it won't synthesize. Quartus site says I can edit the .qsf file, But I couldn't find in my file any

set_global_assignment -name VERILOG_NON_CONSTANT_LOOP_LIMIT 300

Moreover, I'm somehow impressed that the book teach that step with a wrong code, not syntesizable, I also wish to actually fix the problem not to workaround, what can I do?

Update: I tried changing to 'For' but it gives error: 
Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at ADD_SUB_FLO.v(44) near text ">";  expecting "="
I think for or while it wouldn't matter because it seems the problem is that system requires to pre+know the bound, but that's for being calculated.

```
    for ( i=ctrl_align,i>0,i=i-1)
        begin
            fract_a = fract_a >> 1;
            exp_a_bias = exp_a_bias + 1;
        end
```

Comment: The book teaches simulation code, but not synthesis code. You need to restructure your code so it doesn't use a while loop e.g. a for loop (because they have an upper bound). Btw bit 31 is the sign bit, which is not part of the biased exponent. The fractional part has only 23 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a previous comment stated, this isn't synthesizable Verilog. You're getting caught up in thinking sequentially. You don't need a for loop or a while loop, basically, you want `fract_*` to shift, `exp_*_bias` to increment, and `ctrl_align` to decrement after an initial loading.

There are three states:

1. A **loading** state, where `ctrl_align = exp_b_bias - exp_a_bias`
2. A **counting** state, where `ctrl_align` is decremented and the correct `fract_` is shifted
3. A **done** state, where `ctr_align` == 0 and the output is valid

Use a simple state machine to keep track of this and then use a case statement to select the correct assignments for each net.

For example:

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
    // Should include a reset
    case(state):
    LOAD:begin
        ctr_align <= (exp_a_bias < exp_b_bias)? exp_b_bias - exp_a_bias : exp_a_bias - exp_b_bias;
    end
    COUNT:begin
        ctrl_align <= ctrl_align - 8'd1;
        fract_a <= (exp_a_bias < exp_b_bias)? fract_a >> 1 : fract_a;
        fract_b <= (exp_b_bias < exp_a_bias)? fract_b >> 1 : fract_b;
    end
    DONE: ctrl_align <= ctrl_align
    default: ctrl_align <= 0; // latches inferred for fract_*
```

Haven't checked for syntax, and there's some inferred latches, but this should give you the gist of it. The state machine should be trivial to implement, just a few if statements.

Hope that helps!